# Can someone on Basic Plan send Push Notifications?

Tags: notifications, push, codenameone

I am currently on Basic Plan which if I am not mistaken entitles me to 'Push Notifications (5K/month)'. But when I send a request to
https://push.codenameone.com/push/push?...  with my token, I get this error.

{"error":"Unauthorized: pro subscription or higher required for token .... "}.

Please what am I missing?

Comment: Looking into this and will get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the production push servers for some use cases. It should be fixed now. Please try again.

Comment: Yes it's going through now. Thank you!